# Redirect GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent Logging

Tags: macos, google-chrome, logging

I am debugging an issue on my Mac and I am therefore looking through the system logs. One thing I have noticed is the extreme abundance of multi-line messsages from *GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent* like the one below:

```
Jan 13 15:47:55 <<Computer Name>> GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[10829]: 2019-01-13 15:47:55.765 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[10829/0x700009887000] [lvl=2] -[KSEngineInvocation(KeystoneThread) updateProdu
   ticketStore=<KSPersistentTicketStore:0x7fd3e64284c0 store=<KSKeyedPersistentStore:0x7fd3e641b530
       path="/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/TicketStore/Keystone.ticketstore"
       lockFile=<KSLockFile:0x7fd3e6428110
           path="/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/TicketStore/Keystone.ticketstore.lock"
           resolvedPath="/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/TicketStore/Keystone.ticketstore.lock"
           shared=NO       fileSpecificLock=0x7fd3e6414d30>
       keyType=NSString
       valueTypes={(
           KSTicket
       )}
   >>
   processor=<KSActionProcessor:0x7fd3e660d830
       delegate=<KSDaemonUpdateEngine:0x7fd3e88019b0>
       isProcessing=NO actionsCompleted=0 progress=0.00
       errors=0 currentActionErrors=0
       events=0 currentActionEvents=0
       actionQueue=( )
   >
   delegate=<KSEngineInvocation: 0x7f8461727f30>
   serverInfoStore=(null)
   errors=0
```

This adds a ton of clutter to the system log files and makes it much more difficult to find what I am looking for. Is there a way I can redirect all the logging from *GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent* to its own log file instead of `system.log`? How would I do it?

Comment: You may change the update frequency to 7 days with a value of 24 x 3600 x 7 = 604800 : `defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 604800`.

Comment: You might get a better answer on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would filtering out messages you don't want to see from system.log be an acceptable solution?  As described here : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168423/is-there-any-way-of-filtering-out-messages-from-os-x-system-log/272888#272888

Comment: @lx07 Filtering out the messages from the system.log file would indeed be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the default frequency of the Update Agent is too high, it can be reduced.

For example,
to change the update frequency to 7 days with a value of 24 x 3600 x 7 = 604800 :

```
defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 604800.
```

Comment: Hmm... I have executed the command you provided as an example. However, I still see a lot of logging in `system.log` by _GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent_.

Comment: Have a look at the file `/Users/USER/Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone.agent.plist` to verify that the above command has set `StartInterval` to the specified number. If not, then do it yourself. Reboot to see if it has not been reset and is effective.